# Javascript quotes text silder with two sets

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slider

I want to create quotes text slider with 2 sets of data.

fiddle link -> https://jsfiddle.net/628r3t1h/

```js
(function() {

    var quotes = $(".quotes");

    var quoteIndex = -1;
    function showNextQuote() {
        ++quoteIndex;

        quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
        .fadeIn(1500)
        .delay(1000)
        .fadeOut(1000, showNextQuote);
        
    }

    showNextQuote();



})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- set 1 -->
<h1 style="" class="sec1-head">Set 1<br/>
    <span style="" class="quotes sec1-head-quotes">Text 1.1</span>
    <span style="display: none;"  class="quotes sec1-head-quotes">Text 1.2</span>
    <span style="display: none;"  class="quotes sec1-head-quotes">Text 1.3</span>
</h1>
<!-- set 2 -->
<h1 style="" class="sec1-head">Set 2<br/>
    <span style="" class="quotes sec1-head-quotes">Text 2.1</span>
    <span style="display: none;"  class="quotes sec1-head-quotes">Text 2.2</span>
    <span style="display: none;"  class="quotes sec1-head-quotes">Text 2.3</span>
</h1>
```

Here **Set 1** should run 1st and after that **Set 2** should be visible. And the cycle must continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```js
const sets = $(".set");

let set = sets[0], quote = 0;

sets.hide();

$(sets[0]).fadeIn(1500);

function showQuote() {
    if($(set).children().eq(quote).is(':last-child')) {
        if($(set).hasClass("last")) {
            set = $(".set").first();
        } else {
            set = $(set).next();
        }
        sets.hide();
        $(set).fadeIn(1500);
        quote = 1;
    } else {
        ++quote
    }
    
    $(set).children().eq(quote)
        .fadeIn(1500)
        .delay(1000)
        .fadeOut(1000, showQuote);
}

showQuote();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- set 1 -->
<h1 style="" class="sec1-head set">Set 1<br/>
    <span style="" class="quotes sec1-head-quotes">Text 1.1</span>
    <span style="display: none;"  class="quotes sec1-head-quotes">Text 1.2</span>
    <span style="display: none;"  class="quotes sec1-head-quotes">Text 1.3</span>
</h1>
<!-- set 2 -->
<h1 style="" class="sec1-head set last">Set 2<br/>
    <span style="" class="quotes sec1-head-quotes">Text 2.1</span>
    <span style="display: none;"  class="quotes sec1-head-quotes">Text 2.2</span>
    <span style="display: none;"  class="quotes sec1-head-quotes">Text 2.3</span>
</h1>
```